# What's the correct way to observe on the UI thread

Tags: windows-phone-8, system.reactive

I'm building observables over the [Geolocator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.aspx) and events must be subscribed on the UI thread.

Is `ObserveOnDispatcher` deprecated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ObserveOnDispatcher()` is not deprecated, but as Paul says it's generally better to provide an explicit scheduler so you can inject a `TestScheduler` for unit testing.

`DispatcherScheduler.Current` can be used to obtain the current `DispatcherScheduler` - not `.Instance`, which makes sense since there can actually be more than one - although most people shouldn't need to go down that particular road!

`ObserveOnDispatcher()` and `DispatcherScheduler` are present in the Windows Phone 8 Rx build. They are in the `rx-xaml` nuget package which contains xaml platform specific elements - you would have missed this if you just included `rx-main`.

Specifically, they are located in the `System.Reactive.Windows.Threading.dll` assembly. `ObserveOnDispatcher()` is on the `System.Reactive.Linq.DispatcherObservable` type, and the assembly also has `System.Reactive.Concurrency.DispatcherScheduler`.

Comment: `rx-xaml`: that's what I was missing!

Answer (score 2):

I usually write:

```
.ObserveOn(DispatcherScheduler.Instance)
```

if I'm not using [ReactiveUI](https://github.com/reactiveui/reactiveui). If I am, it's

```
.ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
```

The difference being, that in a unit test runner, `RxApp.MainThreadScheduler` is automatically rigged to be `CurrentThread`, so your unit tests pass - otherwise they'll all hang.

Comment: In what namespace and assembly would that `DispatcherScheduler` be? The one I'm finding (`Microsoft.Phone.Reactive.DispatcherScheduler`) is on the C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0\Microsoft.Phone.Reactive.dll, not any of the NuGet packages.